# Making a form with excluding fields to search for flights (iOS app)

Tags: forms, ios, search

I am currently facing a UX situation which I'm not sure how to solve.

I have a place on my app where I can search for flights inputting either the Airline, Departure and Destination airports, or the Flight Number.

One thought was to separate the airline, departure and destination fields from the Flight Number with an OR. I don't like too much this one, as it might be confusing if someone has filled more than one field.

Another could be a picker selecting which type of search (Dep/Dest airports or Flight Number).

What are your thoughts? What other ideas could be better?

Comment: There is another solution to show the first field like "Search by airport or flight number" and when user selects airport from suggestion list, then you can show the rest of the fields

Answer (score 1):

As @Cristian Negraia mentioned that firstly analyze what is the most popular way people are searching the flights and then make it default one.

In iOS app, you can use the tab button to switch between option, Search as heading and tabs labels as "By Flight" and "By route".

iOS native tab can easily be used, image attached for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I would do would be to asses what is the most popular way people are trying to search for a flight. I would separate the searches in two tabs with the most popular one as the primary selected one. Titled somewhere along the lines of Search and Search by flight number.

Or set up as the primary way to search and above it have a switch that says: I know the flight number.) that replaces the search.